# Some TextFields created in database with NOT NULL YES/NO

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.7

I have the following Model:

```
class SystemMessage(Model):
  subject = TextField(default=None)
  message = TextField(default=None)
```

And the following output from `explain`

```
| id            | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| language_code | varchar(5) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| subject       | longtext   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| message       | longtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

I have no outstanding `migrations` or `makemigrations`

Is there any reason why `message` is **NULLable** but `subject` is not? I would like both to be **NOT NULLable**.

I'm provided a default value for each field to ensure `IntegrityError` when saving the strings with no value.

Comment: Don't set any default value just do `subject = TextField()`. And make sure your models are in sync with the database.

Comment: I want to force a value to be provided so that `IntegrityError` is raised if it isn't provided. Is there a better method that does not rely on `full_clean()` ?